# Eliminate loop in numpy - proper broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I have this ugly loop:

```
import numpy as np

in1 = np.array( ( (2.2, 2.5) , 
                  (1.4, 1.7) )
              )
out1 = np.array( ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ) )
idx1 = np.array( ( ( 0, 1 ), 
                   ( 2, 2 ) )
               )

# an ugly loop
for i in xrange(2):
  for j in xrange(2):
    out1[ idx1[i,j] ] += in1[i,j]
```

These loops normally run over a 1000x1000 range. How do I use numpy indexing properly? This doesn't work:

```
out1[ idx1 ] += in1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can flatten the indices and the values to be assigned and then use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to get the output without the need to initialize, like so -

```
out1 = np.bincount(idx1.ravel(), in1.ravel())
```

Alternatively, to add to the initialized output array `out1`, we can use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), like so -

```
np.add.at(out1, idx1.ravel(), in1.ravel())
```

Comment: Perfect! And discovered that at() doesn't need to ravel() arguments